# SQL - Referencing 3 tables

Tags: sql

This is in relation to my survey application for our team. I have 3 tables in my database related to this problem.

I apologize if the database is not fully normalized.

```
TBL_CHURCH columns:

1 FAM_CHURCH_SACRMNT_NUM (Primary Key) Int(15)
2 RSPONDNT_NUM
3 SURVYR_NUM
4 QN_NUMBER
5 CHRCHFAMLY_NAME
6 CHRCHFAMLY_ISBAPTIZED

 Sample row based on order of columns above:
         1            2         3        4           5               6
      6422164     76826499    5712      362    Serio Tecson Jr.     Yes

TBL_INTRVW columns:

1 QN_NUMBR (Primary Key)
2 SURVYR_NUM
3 ZONE_NUM
4 RSPONDNT_NUM

  Sample row based on order of columns above:
         1            2           3           4
        362          5712         11        76826499

TBL_AREA columns:
1 BRGY_ZONE_NUM (Primary Key)
2 BRGY_CODE

  Sample row based on order of columns above:
         1            2
        11           2A
        21           2A
        31           2A
```

The field CRCHFAMLY_ISBAPTIZED has only two values. A "Yes" or a "No" and each row has a QN_NUMBR value that is referenced to TBL_INTRVW and each QN_NUMBR on TBL_INTRVW has a unique ZONE_NUM that is referenced to TBL_AREA and that ZONE_NUM has a corresponding BRGY_CODE. Each BRGY_CODE have at least 2 ZONE_NUM values

My problem is that I want to count the number of people baptized in a given area.

The output more or less should look like this: 
(The output is collected from the 3 different ZONE_NUM)

```
 Zone Name    Num of People Baptized
   2A                   20
```

I'm having what trouble what to use in my SQL statements. Should I use a WHERE within an INNER JOIN? And how do I go about in my SELECT statements?

Comment: Is there a column that gives the no. of people baptised in a church?

Comment: @RashmiPandit None. The number of people baptised in a church is not part of the parameters given to us. They only specified how many people are baptised in a given area. And that includes any churches within that area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.BRGY_ZONE_NUM,count(a.CHRCHFAMLY_ISBAPTIZED) as [Num of People Baptized]
from TBL_CHURCH a
left join 
TBL_INTRVW b
on a.QN_NUMBER=b.QN_NUMBER
left join 
TBL_AREA c
on b.ZONE_NUM=cRGY_ZONE_NUM
where a.CHRCHFAMLY_ISBAPTIZED='Yes'
group by  c.BRGY_ZONE_NUM
```

I dont see Zone Name column on the three table, so i used BRGY_ZONE_NUM